# TypeScript 'never' on class member in catch?

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors, try-catch

TypeScript version 2.2.1.

I have just started trying out TypeScript, and keep getting an error I dont understand. I have strictNullChecks set to true, because I want to define which types can be nulled. So I have this class:

```
class Core {
    client: MessagesClient | null;

    connect(server: string, port: number, connectionHandler: ConnectionHandler) {
        if(this.client) {
            this.client.disconnect(false, "New connection");
            this.client = null;
        }

        try {
            this.client = new MessagesClient(server, port);
            functionWhichCanThrow(); //I.e, lot of other code which I didn't include    
        } catch(exception) {
            let error = "Error while setting up connection: " + exception;
            if(this.client) {
                this.client.disconnect(true, error);
                this.client = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, inside the catch statement, the TypeScript compiler insists that this.client can never be anything other than null. Thus this.client.disconnect throws an error: error TS2339: Property 'disconnect' does not exist on type 'never'.

I want to disconnect if it throws an exception, which can happen at any point AFTER this.client has been set.

Not setting this.client to null at the beginning of connect removes the error, but I want to understand why this is happening.
Am I overlooking something completely obvious here?

EDIT:
Another shorter example

```
class Test {
    test: string | null;

    doTest() {
        this.test = null;
        try {
            this.test = "test";
            throw new Error("");
        } catch(e) {
            if(this.test) //Visual Studio Code say that this is "null", not "string | null"
                this.test.replace("test", "error"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Been staring at this for like 4 minutes and it seems to check out. Leaning towards a glitch on TS's part, although I hate playing that card.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you change the condition in the catch to `this.client != null`?

Comment: Same thing. And another interesting example: this.t = null; try { t = "test"; throw new Error(""); } catch(e) { t; }. Here Visual Studio Code will say t is null in the catch.

Comment: What happens if you're doing `this.client!.disconnect(true, error);`? (notice the `!`)

Comment: If I do that, then the error disappears, and VSCode tells me the type(At that point) is "MessageClient | null". However, should that really be necessary in this case?

Comment: Your 2nd example compiles just fine for me using version `2.2.1` with and without the `--strictNullChecks` flag. Have you tried to compile it using `tsc` instead of doing it inside VSCode?

Comment: Ops, sorry, the second example wasn't complete. Fixed it. It should print the same 'x does not exist on "never" ' when compiling, both inside VSCode and when calling tsc directly. However, the same fix works there, even though I feel its just hiding the problem rather than fixing it.

Comment: It's not hiding the problem, it's exactly what this thing is for ([Non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the type checker is not considering the code inside the try block, since this block has failed. The "last known good code" related to `test` property is: `this.test = null` before the `try` block. If you change this to `this.test = "..."` for example, it will work.

To fix it, you will need to use the `!` post-fix operator:

```
this.test!.replace("test", "error");
```